# retrieving data from Firebase database in android studios with the kotlin language

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to the firebase database and is still learning a few things about it. I am trying to pull out data from the real-time database and I am having a hard time doing it.

my database layout is like this.

```
users 
      --UId
           --firstname
           --lastname
           --dateofbirth
           --mobile
           --email
           --type
```

my user model

```
data class User(val uid: String? = "",
                val Firstname:String = "",
                val Lastname:String = "",
                val Mobile:String ="",
                val Dateofbirth:String ="",
                val email:String = "",
                val type: String = ""
){
    constructor(): this ("","","","","","","")
}
```

I am trying to pull out firstname, lastname, mobile, dateofbirth and email and attach it to my profile textfields for them fname,lname,dob,email

This is the code I am working with

```
 private fun getUserInfo() {
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val uidRef = ref.child("users").child(uid)
        val valueEventListener: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (I in dataSnapshot.children){



            }

            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("error", databaseError.message)

            }

        }
        uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
    }
```

How do I pull out that information?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended to use camel case naming scheme for property names like this:

```
val firstName: String = " "
val secondName: String = " "
```

You can pull user info like this:

```
 private fun getUserInfo() {
        val uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val uidRef = ref.child("users").child(uid)
        val valueEventListener: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)
                //user.firstName
                //user.lastName
                //...
               
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("error", databaseError.message)

            }

        }
        uidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener)
    }
```

Comment: Link not working

Comment: can't find anything on how I am supposed to filter that info and attach it into the user profile area of the UI on my android application                                                                                                user?.firstName
                user?.lastName
                user?.email
                user?.Mobile
                user?.dateOfBirth                                                           it also coming out like this.